# Nebular googleauth getting user info

Tags: google-authentication, nebular

I'm using NbOAuth2AuthStrategy.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJDz5.png]

No problem with login or retreiving access token, but when i'm trying get info about user by token using this
[image]

There is a troubles:

[image]

[image]

i tried use localhost and https://ngrok for ssl but it stil doesnt work, what is problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the url to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=<your_access_token>
```

and you should retrieve a JSON with these properties:

```
sub
name
given_name
family_name
picture
locale
```